# Concatenate all directories names and append to each path

Tags: powershell

How do I modify the result of executing this ps script:

```
(Get-ChildItem -Path E:\Logs\Application -Filter "*Log*" -Recurse -Directory).Fullname
```

to concatenate `\*.log` to each, like this:

```
E:\Logs\application\Service1\logs\*.log
E:\Logs\application\Service2\logs\*.log
E:\Logs\application\Service3\logs\*.log
```

Thanks

Comment: Are you _not_ currently getting them in that order? Please show a sample of the "wrong" output you're currently getting

Comment: Sorry, formatting took out the "\*.log" to the end of each directory.
I get them in order but I am unable to append to to each line the \\*.log

Comment: My question still stands: are you _not_ currently getting the output in that order? If not, please show us sample output

Comment: I was trying to (Get-ChildItem -Path E:\Logs\Application -Filter "*Log*" -Recurse -Directory).Fullname + \\*.log to the end of each entry.

Comment: My bad, the previous wording of the question made it sound like you were having troubles with the sort order in which they were output :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the `Join-Path` cmdlet:

```
$directories = Get-ChildItem -Path E:\Logs\Application -Filter "*Log*" -Recurse -Directory 

$logGlobPaths = $directories |Join-Path -Path {$_.FullName} -ChildPath '*.log'
```

`$logGlobPaths` now contains an array of the desired strings

Comment: Thanks, Mathias. Is there the script works but it lists all directories in one line. Is there anyway I can split each entry on its only line by adding a carriage return? I tried adding $cr = "`r`n" to the end like $logGlobPaths = $directories |Join-Path -Path {$_.FullName} -ChildPath '*.log' $cr but that broke the script

Comment: `$logGlobPaths -join [Envirvonment]::NewLine` will give you one big multi-line string with each path on a new line. `$logGlobPaths |Set-Content path\to\output.txt` should also write each string on a separate line